# kde plasma autostart does not honor redirection or multiple commands

Tags: linux, kde-plasma, autostart

I used to have an autostart login script in archlinux/kde, that had the following exec line:

```
Exec=rmdir /var/tmp/screensaver.lock; /home/user/bin/screensaver.sh > /tmp/screensaver.log 2>&1
```

but now for some reason it stopped working. If I write it like this:

```
Exec=/home/user/bin/screensaver.sh
```

it works.

It looks like kde can't handle the multiple commands and the redirections. why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this. Run everything inside 'bash -c' command.

```
Exec=bash -c "rmdir /var/tmp/screensaver.lock; /home/user/bin/screensaver.sh > /tmp/screensaver.log 2>&1"
```